# c# Avoid empty characters on maskedTextBox

Tags: c#, substring, is-empty, maskedtextbox, isnullorempty

I've read a lot about how to **avoid** `empty maskedtextbox` but none of the worked

In a **click** of a button I sepperate the `maskedTextBox` to **three** `string` , so when `substring` comes the application crash .

Is there anyway that I can **replace** the `empty` characters with "0" and then add them into a string , or something like that ?

**CODE:**

```
        void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string masked = Maskedtextboxes[Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Tag)].Text;

            string hh = masked.Substring(0,2), mm = masked.Substring(3,2),
            ss = masked.Substring(6,2);

            MessageBox.Show(hh+mm+ss);
        }
```

*my maskedtextbox is masked in --/--/--*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
  var p = masked.Split('/');
  // here you could check for p.Length == 3
  string hh = p[0].Trim().PadLeft(2, '0');
  string mm = p[1].Trim().PadLeft(2, '0');
  string ss = p[2].Trim().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

Comment: thank you very much that was  excactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

you van try somethings like this

```
private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] masked = mymaskedTextBox.Text.Split('/');

    string hh = masked[0];
    string mm = masked[1];
    string ss = masked[2];

    MessageBox.Show(hh + mm + ss);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much now at least my app does not crash